# Determine $x$ such that $2x^2 - x - 6$ be a multiple of $53$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, quadratics

I used the modular arithmetic :
$$2x^2 - x - 6  \equiv 0  \mod 53$$
and then : 
$$(2x+3)(x-2) \equiv 0 \mod 53$$

I'm stuck here and don't know what to do with $AB \equiv 0  \mod C$

Comment: Hint: If $x$ is 2 mod 53, what would happen? Can you apply this idea in other cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $53$ is prime, it divides either $x-2$ or $2x+3$. Thus $x\equiv 2,\,25\,(\operatorname{mod}53)$.

Comment: If we put another number instead of $53$ , for example $54$ , what we can do then ?

Comment: @S.H.W. That's tricky because for composite numbers there are a number of factorisations that would work. In general, however, there will be a set of modulo classes of $x$ that comprise the solution, so you could always just go through all of them.

Comment: @S.H.W That's more complex, since the ring $\mathbb{Z}_{54}$ has zero divisors.

Comment: Okay , thanks . Do you know any geometric solution for this problem ?

Comment: @S.H.W What do you mean by geometric? BTW one thing you could do is write $54$ as a product of prime powers ($2\times 27$), then solve simultaneous equations. Since $x-2,\,2x+3$ can't both be divisible by $3$, one will in fact be divisible by $27$.

Comment: $A \equiv 0 \mod C \times D \iff A \equiv 0 \mod C \ \ and \ \ A \equiv 0 \mod D $ is that right ?

Comment: @S.H.W provided $C,\,D$ are co-prime.

Comment: I didn't know LHS implies RHS in this case , thanks a lot .

Answer (score 2):

It follows from your computations that $x=2$ will work.

If you're after *all* solutions (modulo $53$), you do\begin{align}(2x+3)(x-2)\equiv0\pmod{53}&\iff 2x+3\equiv0\pmod{53}\vee x-2\equiv0\pmod{53}\\&\iff2x\equiv50\pmod{53}\vee x\equiv2\pmod{53}\\&\iff x\equiv25\pmod{53}\vee x\equiv2\pmod{53}.\end{align}

Comment: If we put another number instead of $53$ , for example $54$ , what we can do then ?

Answer (score 2):

See [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma). $53$ divides the product $(2x+3)(x-2)$. Then $53$ divides one of them, or both. You now have all the cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can do also like this. Multiply this with $8$
$$2x^2 - x - 6  \equiv 0  \mod 53$$
so 
$$16x^2 - 8x - 48  \equiv 0  \mod 53$$
so
$$16x^2 - 8x +1- 49  \equiv 0  \mod 53$$
so
$$(4x-1)^2   \equiv 7^2  \mod 53$$
so 
$$4x-1   \equiv \pm 7  \mod 53$$
...

---

**Note** that if you have
$$ax^2+bx+c\equiv 0  \mod d$$
and $\gcd(2a,d) =1$ then you can do this always (multiply with $4a$):
$$4a^2x^2+4abx+4ac\equiv 0  \mod d$$
so
$$4a^2x^2+4abx+b^2\equiv b^2-4ac  \mod d$$
$$(2ax+b)^2\equiv \Delta   \mod d$$ where $\Delta = b^2-4ac$.

Answer (score 0):

$53=1*53$(it is a prime number)

So once let, $2x+3=53$
And second time let $x-2=53$
For (i) $x=25$
$\Rightarrow$ $Number=53*27$

Similarly for (ii) $x=55$
$\Rightarrow$ $Number=53*113$

Now considering another case when $53|2x+3$ or $53|x-2$
Which means (i) $53n=2x+3$ (Here n can take any odd integral value)
OR
(ii) $53n=x-2$(here n can take any integral value)

It means there can't be any discrete value/s of x